# What's the alternative of using Cmd+\ in InDesign to align text?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, page-layout, typesetting, shortcuts

My co-worker is the one who taught me this short key in InDesign. It's very useful to align content for a much cleaner look, but it can only be used if the content is in the same paragraph or separated by using a soft break.

I've attached an image of text with and without use of the quick key. It's impossible to find, considering I don't know the name of the action.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature is called '[Indent to Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/tabs-indents.html)' and is found in the menu via 'Type → Insert Special Character → Other'. The alternative to this is using proper bullets, which is [well documented](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/bullets-numbering.html) in the official docs. This is set up as a paragraph style so works better for repeated instances where you can quickly apply the style without having to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> every time. Also, the actual bullet character (which can be customized to any character) and the spacing around it get inserted automatically.

Comment: The alternative in the particular case illustrated in the question; not necessarily in other contexts where an indent-to-here character is used.